# Placing text in an Image object

Tags: image, text, sfml

I am using SFML 2.1 and have an Image with some objects that I would like to number, i.e. I have a set of origin coordinates for each of them so I would place the number there.

However, I can't seem to find a good way to do this: the most relevant function seems to be `Image::copy()` which places a rectangle in the image. To use that, I would have to create a number map image and then do offsets for successive numbers, which seems tedious, cumbersome and unreliable, as an image with too many objects would eventually run out of numbers.

I also thought of conceivably using a `RenderWindow` object and printing the Image along with numbers as `sf::Text` objects with the right coordinates, but the API does not seem to provide a way to save the contents of the window to an image.

So the question is: is there a straightforward way to place numbers (text in general) in an `Image` object?

Answer (score 1):

Your question is rather unclear, thus I guess the negative ratings.

If you want to render text, you can simply draw an `sf::Text` object to an `sf::RenderWindow` object. If you want to reuse the final result you can switch out the `sf::RenderWindow` with a `sf::RenderTexture`. If you want to manipulate single pixels, you'll have to go with an `sf::Image`, but keep in mind the conversion from image to texture is a slow process, so don't do it, if it isn't necessary.

See the official [documentation](http://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.1/) and [tutorials](http://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.1/) on how to work with SFML.