# Copy RenderTexture to Image

Tags: c++, image, opencv, sfml, deep-copy

I'm trying to copy `sf::RenderTexture` (with `sf::Image` & `sf::Text` on it), to Opencv Mat object. We can convert an `sf::Image` to `cv::Mat` (Opencv) by

```
sf::Image img;
cv::Size size(img.getSize().x, img.getSize().y);    
cv::Mat mat(size,CV_8UC4, (void*)img.getPixelsPtr(), cv::Mat::AUTO_STEP);
cv::cvtColor(mat, mat, cv::COLOR_RGBA2BGRA);
```

as far as I know, in SFML we cannot add text directly to `sf::Image` but we have to use RenderWindow or RenderTexture for that. I guess only workaround is to load objects in following order

> sf::Image --> sf::Texture --> sf::Sprite -->sf::RenderTexture
>
> sf::Text --> sf::RenderTexture

Finally Copy RenderTexture to sf::Image then convert it to cv::Mat
I suppose it will take long time to copy sf::RenderTexture back to sf::Image.
any other workaround for this?  like using sf::Image::loadFromMemory();

P.S: Some references [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20559383/placing-text-in-an-image-object) & [here](https://github.com/SFML/SFML/issues/190)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there isn't really an alternative when it comes to SFML. Copying from VRAM to RAM isn't very fast, but should still be able to perform at a okay-ish framerate. Maybe you should just give it a try and see whether the performance does really impact your scenario.

The issue here is that SFML operates in the GPU space, so text rendering is made for rendering with your GPU similar thing with sprite, but what you actually seem to want is CPU rendering of text and sprites.

If you only translate sprites (no scaling/rotating) it should be relatively easy to build such functionality on top of `sf::Image`.

For text rendering you might want to use freetype directly and not move the font data to the GPU.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  can you elaborate a bit on _"you might want to use freetype directly and not move the font data to the GPU"_

Comment: Freetype is a library used to load and render fonts. SFML uses freetype internally and then uploads the rendered characters as sf::Textures to the GPU. Since you want a "software" renderer you can use freetype on your own and just render to "RAM". How you do that, is beyond this question.